# Eslint rule to catch variable usage without assignment

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there an eslint rule which warns about variable being used before it is assigned a value?

```
let foo;
somefunction(foo);
```

In the above I would like to get an error on second line saying foo was used without any assigned value.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare does this help?

Comment: Sorry but no... I am not re-declaring anything here..

Comment: Not sure there's necessarily a rule for this situation. If `someFunction()` accepts `undefined`, then this is perfectly valid code. JavaScript doesn't have a notion of "uninitialized", everything is auto-initialized to the value `undefined` if there's no assignment expression in the declaration statement, and this is common knowledge.